# How to write test case for if else with htmlelement in karma jasmine test case?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

```
**Component code:**
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event', '$event.target'])
onClick(event: MouseEvent, targetElement: HTMLElement): void| boolean {
try {
  this.shareService.addBreadCrumb('Host listener other than helpbox...');
  if (targetElement.className === 'fa fa-question-circle-o' || targetElement.className === 'info-icon') {
    return false;
  }
  this.isHelpboxVisible = null;
} catch (e) {
  Sentry.captureException(e);
}
```

}

I want to code cover the following part:

```
if (targetElement.className === 'fa fa-question-circle-o' || targetElement.className === 'info-icon') {
    return false;
  }
```

Please suggest how can I proceed. What I have tried ( I am new to unit testing):

```
it('should return false for specific classname', () => {
document.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.fa fa-question-circle-o.info-icon'));
const result = component.onClick(new MouseEvent('click'), 'test' as any);
expect(result).toBe(false);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just mock the html element like so:

```
it('should return false for specific classname', () => {
const result = component.onClick(new MouseEvent('click'), { className: 'fa fa-question-circle-o' } as any);
expect(result).toBe(false);
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I am new to this so asking silly questions may be... But it helped me a lot